# d3 variable equals the string "function(d)", not the value the function returns

Tags: function, variables, d3.js

In some d3js code, I am using an anonymous `function(d)` to return the value of `-importance` from a JSON file. I use the returned value, stored in `kwdAssbly` object, to decide whether or not to render part of a diagram.

where I break on:

```
kwdAssbly.opt = (function(d){
  return d["-importance"];
});
```

With a watch set on the object `kwdAssbly`, the debugger shows numerical values for `kwdAssbly.width` & `kwdAssbly.height` but shows `kwdAssbly.opt = kwdAssbly.opt(d)`. I'm expecting a string value of either `required` or `optional`! If I put a watch on `d` in the function, it shows `-importance:"optional"`, but this isn't assigned to my `kwdAssbly.opt` object attribute

Why is the function declaration being returned as the value?

Here's a code snippet of the context:

```
      .attr("nullAttrib", function(d, i) {  // calculate the  text width and store it
        var kwdAssbly = {}; //the keyword group's height and width object
        kwdAssbly.width = this.getBoundingClientRect().width + padding;
        kwdAssbly.height = this.getBoundingClientRect().height;
        kwdAssbly.opt = (function(d){
          return d["-importance"];
        });

       kwdProps[i] = kwdAssbly;
        if (i>0){
          kwdX += kwdProps[i-1].width;
          if (kwdProps[i].opt == "optional"){
            OptOffset = 40;
            var Lsiding = kwdgrp.append(function(){return sidingL})
              .attr("transform","translate(" + kwdX + ", " + (kwdProps[i].height*2/3 + line1y + OptOffset) + ")");
            var Rsiding = kwdgrp.append(function(){return sidingR})
              .attr("transform","translate(" + kwdX+50 + ", " + (kwdProps[i].height*2/3 + line1y + OptOffset) + ")");
          }
          else {
            OptOffset = 0;
          }             
        }
```

Comment: You won't need an anonymous function to get the string value. Just use `kwdAssbly.opt = d["-importance"];`

Comment: Thanks altocumulus. Schoolboy error on my part. I'm just getting to grips with d3 :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working/correct answer by Altocumulus:

You won't need an anonymous function to get the string value.

Just use `kwdAssbly.opt = d["-importance"];`

Comment: actually, you *do need* a function. The thing is that the function is already there (line 1).

Comment: @GerardoFurtado No, you don't! This question is not about the anonymous callback provided to `.attr()` but rather about the one assigned to `kwdAssbly.opt`. This one is not only *not* needed but, because it never gets called, it is not returning the expected value.